# Get column details from one table using another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have got 2 tables

```
orders
orderid | productid | userid | qty

products
productid | productname | productdesc
```

products.productid is Foreign Key to orders
I want to get the order details for a userid.
and display products details for a productid and the qty from orders table.

What could be the query?

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

Join the two tables.

```
select
    *
from orders o
join products p
on o.productid = p.productid
where o.userid = 123;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check This Out:

```
SELECT * FROM orders INNER JOIN products ON orders.productid = products .productid
```

Answer (score 0):

Just join the tables

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
JOIN products ON orders.productid = products.productid
ORDER BY userid
```

...and optionally filter it for a given userid. I.e. Orders of userid 555:

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
JOIN products ON orders.productid = products.productid
WHERE userid = 555
```